# Performance related to multiple for loops vs single for loop wrt getting data from multimap

Tags: c++, performance, memory, data-structures, compilation

Below is the sample code of fetching data from a multimap and assigning to a typedef struct. I need to know if there is any performance difference/advantage/disadvantage in fetching data using multiple for loops compared to single for loop. Here dbR25GetRoute is the multimap.

```
            int sz = dbR25GetRoute.size();
            int indivi = sz/28;
            if(!pGetRoute && (0 < indivi)) {
                pGetRoute = new R25GetRoute[indivi];
            }

            if(pGetRoute) {
                typename DBMULTIMAP::const_iterator iter = dbR25GetRoute.begin();
                for (int cnt = 0; (iter != dbR25GetRoute.end()) && (cnt < indivi); iter++, cnt++) {         
                    pGetRoute[cnt].costPrice = GetDBVal<double>(iter->second);
                }

                for (int cnt = 0; (iter != dbR25GetRoute.end()) && (cnt < indivi); iter++, cnt++)   {           
                    pGetRoute[cnt].access = GetDBVal<std::string>(iter->second);
                }
                ..... total 28 for loops
            }
```

instead of single loop

```
            if(pGetRoute) {
            typename DBMULTIMAP::const_iterator iter = dbR25GetRoute.begin();
            for (int cnt = 0; (iter != dbR25GetRoute.end()); iter++, cnt++) {                                       
                T data = GetDBVal<double>(iter->second);
                /// Call some functionality here to save T data
            }
```

I would like to use the multiple option scenario because it suites my coding scenario. But need to know if it has a disadvantage related to it.

Comment: Have you tried and had any performance issues?

Comment: Actually no, but i need to know because i got a comment from my colleague saying that multiple for loops are more expensive and time consuming. I need to know the truth behind this.

Comment: At least multiple for loops is extra code to maintain and to understand. If you try to modify the multiple loops logic you will need to change it in multiple places, and such code is prone to bug.

Comment: Ok agree to that, but regarding the performance related any inputs?

Comment: I am not iterating the container multiple times. iterator only starts from the begin once. So N is still same for both the condition.

Comment: Please describe how exactly you add data to dbR25GetRoute and how it is arranged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether there is a *significant* difference in performance can really only be answered by you, by actually measuring the performance in the execution environment where this code will be used.

It seems to me a trade-off. Good things about 28 separate for-loops:

- No extra logic to figure out the type to extract from the multi-map.

Bad things about 28 separate for-loops:

- Slightly larger loop overhead checking `cnt < indivi` for each loop.
- pGetRoute is accessed from beginning to end 28 separate times, making it more likely to exceed cache limits and produce slower access as a result of cache misses.
- 28 separate for-loops is harder to maintain or modify. Normally I would think this takes precedence over the most-likely-insignificant performance issues above. But again, only you can determine if that's really the case.